# why is my javascript object method returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm a beginner in both javascript oop and game programming too(!) .
Here i've created a game player with a method. but the method is returning undefined. why is that?,

```
bobsGame = {};

bobsGame.player  = function(which){
  this.which = which;
  this.rollDice = function () {
    diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    console.log(diceVal);
    return diceVal;
  }
}

var player1 = new bobsGame.player('player1');
```

and then in the markup…

```
$('#roll-dice-btn-1').click(function(){
  bobsGame.player1.rollDice();
});
```

Comment: There are too many incoherent things in here. Where is defined `bobsgame.player1` for example ? Can you build a working fiddle demonstrating your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bobsGame.player1` is undefined because `player1` was not declared within the object `bobsGame`.
If you want to create `player1` as a key in your `bobsGame` object, you must use `bobsGame.player1 = new bobsGame.player('player1');` instead. So your code would look like:
bobsGame = {};

```
bobsGame.player  = function(which){
  this.which = which;
  this.rollDice = function () {
    diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    console.log(diceVal);
    return diceVal;
  }
}

var player1 = new bobsGame.player('player1');
```

Otherwise, you can use:

```
$('#roll-dice-btn-1').click(function(){
  player1.rollDice();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `bobsGame.player1` in your class, you just instanciated a new instance to the variable `player1` ?

```
var player1 = new bobsGame.player('player1');

$('#roll-dice-btn-1').click(function(){
    player1.rollDice();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VkGrT/)

Comment: This. You aren't currently calling the `rollDice()` method on the `player1` object you created.

Comment: @egl - Then what am I calling ?

Comment: Your answer is fine, was referring to the OP calling the method incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your call should be `player1.rollDice()` like

```
  $('#roll-dice-btn-1').click(function(){
    player1.rollDice();
  });
```

You are confused between `player` property of bobsGame object and the `player1` object you actually created.

Answer (score 2):

this might work a little better

```
bobsGame.player1 = new bobsGame.player('player1');
```

Comment: And why would you instanciate the class to a property of itself ?

Comment: Or just replace bobsGame completely

Answer (score 1):

You can play with a structure like that:

```
bobsGame = function(opts) {
    this.player = opts.player;
    this.diceVal = 0;
}

bobsGame.prototype.rollDice  = function(){
    this.diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
}
```

And in your main file:

```
var player1 = new bobsGame({player: 'player1'});
$('#roll-dice-btn-1').click(function(){
    player1.rollDice();
    console.log(player1.diceVal);
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MF3W4/)

Answer (score 1):

slight problem with your. It cannot find `bobsGame.player1` in your class. So change like this and it would work fine..

```
bobsGame.player  = function(which){
    this.which = which;

    this.rollDice = function(){
        diceVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        console.log(diceVal);
        return diceVal;
    }
}


     var player1 = new bobsGame.player('player1');
    player1.rollDice();
```